# Fast INT(LOG2(value))

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to convert a days-since-last-activity value in my SQL Server stored procedure to a logarithmic representation for weighted ordering (alongside other criteria) of the matching search results before truncating them. Log2 approximates my needs pretty well and seems like something that should be very efficient.

```
CAST (LOG(lastActivityAge)/LOG(2)) AS TINYINT
```

Would work fine, but it seems extremely wasteful to ask my server to do such heavy lifting just to get the highest set bit position.

Any suggestions on a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: How big do your values get? It might be worth considering a lookup table.

Comment: @AakashM: I'd extend it out to about 4 years before the age was irrelevant. I could go by weeks without losing much value, so about 200 rows. Thanks for the idea.

Comment: Have you timed this to see how slow it is?  Compared to I/O, even logs may be pretty fast.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some [bit twiddling hacks](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerLogObvious) to find the highest bit but they cannot be expressed easily in T-SQL (requiring loops). UDF's are out of questions for performance reasons.

You can go a little bit faster with Denali:

```
CAST (LOG(lastActivityAge, 2)) AS TINYINT
```

Or hard-code the `LOG(2)` expression as I'm not sure the optimizer can constant-fold it away. Anyway, you need millions of rows to notice the difference.

One last trick: If there are some very common values, try this:

```
case lastActivityAge when 1 then 0 when 2 then 1 /* ... */ else CAST (LOG(lastActivityAge, 2)) AS TINYINT end
```

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware. Unfortunately I'm not at Denali yet. It will probably be about a year for that upgrade. I'm at about 10K rows in most of the applicable searches. Spatial searches are the real bugger, but I'm running the margin pretty tightly on user experience right now, and already have a bunch of UI tricks in-place to make it look faster.

Comment: I have added one last trick. Anyway, arithmetic is so incredibly cheap compared to just a single row lookup. Maybe you should look elsewhere for potential (or at least profile SQL Server using perfview to make sure the log function is important).